# SQL Server: attach database with filestream error 5

Tags: restore, filestream, attach

I'm trying to attach a database with full text catalog and filestream, but I'm having some issues with the file stream part. Here's the SQL I'm using (according to this [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1878/how-to-detach-and-attach-a-sql-server-filestream-enabled-database/), this should work):

```
use master
go


create database [Demov2] ON
(FILENAME = N'D:\Demo\Demov2.MDF'),
(FILENAME = N'D:\Demo\SQLFullTextCatalog\DemoV2_FullTextCatalog.ndf'),
(FILENAME = N'D:\Demo\LogsSQLSRA\Demov2_1.LDF'),
FILEGROUP [FileStreamGroup] contains filestream default
(Name = N'Demo_Files', FILENAME = N'D:\Demo\SQLFilestream')
for attach
go
```

This results in a error:

```
Msg 5120, Level 16, State 101, Line 5
Unable to open the physical file "D:\Demo\SQLFilestream". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".
Msg 1802, Level 16, State 7, Line 5
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.
```

I've tried running this as `sa`  and as a windows user but the result is always the same. I've also checked the folder permissions and I've added my windows account and SQL Server's service account with full control to the `D:\Demo` folder and made sure that it was propagated to its children folder:

[image]

Btw, I'm using an instance running this version od SQL

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-GDR) (KB5021522) - 16.0.1050.5 (X64)   
Jan 23 2023 17:02:42   
Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  
Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 22621: ) (Hypervisor)
```

It's clearly a permissions issue, but can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found what I was missing: the path the filesstream folder was missing the last name:

```
FILEGROUP [FileStreamGroup] contains filestream default
(Name = N'Demo_Files', FILENAME = N'D:\Demo\SQLFilestream\Demov2_Files')
```